# ASP.NET: ValidationSummary doesn't display any contents

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm trying to figure out how the heck the validation summary control of ASP.NET (3.5 I think) works.

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vldSummary" runat="server" DisplayMode="BulletList" 
  CssClass="error" EnableClientScript="true" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldSubject" ControlToValidate="txtSubject"
  EnableClientScript="false" Text="You must enter a subject." runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldMessage" ControlToValidate="txtMessage"
  EnableClientScript="false" runat="server" Text="You must enter a message." />
```

It seems that no matter what I do, the validation summary remains empty (but *is* rendered) and the errors are only displayed at the position of each respective validator.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Text` property's value is what is displayed beside the control.  You need to set the `ErrorMessage` property of the validators to control what is shown in the summary.

Answer (score 3):

You want to set the `ErrorMessage` property on your validation controls. This text will be displayed by the `ValidationSummary` control.

Try:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vldSummary" runat="server" DisplayMode="BulletList" CssClass="error" EnableClientScript="true" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldSubject" ControlToValidate="txtSubject" EnableClientScript="false" ErrorMessage="You must enter a subject." runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldMessage" ControlToValidate="txtMessage" EnableClientScript="false" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must enter a message." />
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `ErrorMessage` property on the RequiredFieldValidators, not the `Text` property.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldSubject" ControlToValidate="txtSubject" EnableClientScript="false" ErrorMessage="You must enter a subject." runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vldMessage" ControlToValidate="txtMessage"  EnableClientScript="false" runat="server" ErrorMessage="You must enter a message." />
```